# in array function php

Tags: php, arrays

I use `in_array()` to check whether a value exists in an array like below,
But does not work as expected:

```
$projectId = $_GET['projectId'];
$userId = $_GET['userId'];

$qr2 = mysql_query("SELECT `userId`,`status` FROM `fndn_ProjectBacker` WHERE `projectId`='$projectId' && `status`='1'");

for($i = 1; $row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr2); $i++) {
    $arr1[$i] = array($row2);
}

if (in_array($userId, $arr1)) {
    echo "True";
}
```

plz help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work as you want it, because you create a two dimensional array with this:

```
$arr1[$i]=array($row2);
        //^^^^^^     ^ See here
```

Remove the array declaration here and you can also change out your for loop with a while loop, e.g.

```
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr2)){
    $arr1[] = $row2["userId"];
}

if (in_array($userId, $arr1)) {
    echo "True";
}
```

---

I also want to welcome you in 2015 and highly recommend to use [`mysqli_* prepared statements`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), they are much safer. (Also see: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/3933332))

Comment: @FatemehNamkhah What does *not work* mean? Do you get any errors? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s): `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>` Also what is the output of: `print_r($arr1);` after the while loop?

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [userId] => 0 [status] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [userId] => 5 [status] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [userId] => 25 [status] => 1 )...

Comment: @FatemehNamkhah updated my answer. Just reload the page and try the code again. You just need to add the userid to your array.